# Searching Perl array with regex and return single capturing group only

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl script in which I perform web service calls in a loop. The server returns a multivalued HTTP header that I need to parse after each call with information that I will need to make the next call (if it doesn't return the header, I want to exit the loop).

I only care about one of the values in the header, and I need to get the information out of it with a regular expression. Let's say the header is like this, and I only care about the "foo" value:

```
X-Header: test-abc12345; blah=foo
X-Header: test-fgasjhgakg; blah=bar
```

I can get the header values like this: `@values = $response->header( 'X-Header' );`. But how do I quickly check if

1. There is a foo value, and
2. Parse and save the foo value for the next iteration?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
my $value = 'default';

do {
  # (do HTTP request; use $value)
  @values = $response->header( 'X-Header' );
} while( $value = first { /(?:test-)([^;]+)(?:; blah=foo)/ } @values );
```

But `grep`, `first` (from `List::Util`), etc. all return the entire *match* and not just the single capturing group I want. I want to avoid cluttering up my code by looping over the array and matching/parsing inside the loop body.

Is what I want possible? What would be the most compact way to write it? So far, all I can come up with is using lookarounds and `\K` to discard the stuff I don't care about, but this isn't super readable and makes the regex engine perform a lot of unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that you want to catch the first element with a certain pattern, but acquire only the pattern.  And you want it done nicely. Indeed, `first` and `grep` only pass the element itself.

However, [List::MoreUtils::first_result](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#firstres-BLOCK-LIST) does support processing of its match

```
use List::MoreUtils 0.406 qw(first_result);

my @w = qw(a bit c dIT);  # get first "it" case-insensitive

my $res = first_result { ( /(it)/i )[0] } @w;

say $res // 'undef';  #--> it
```

That `( ... )[0]` is needed to put the regex in the list context so that it returns the actual capture. Another way would be `firstres { my ($r) = /(it)/i; $r }`. Pick your choice

---

For the data in the question

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::MoreUtils 0.406 qw(firstres);

my @data = ( 
    'X-Header: test-abc12345; blah=foo',
    'X-Header: test-fgasjhgakg; blah=bar'
);

if (my $r = firstres { ( /test-([^;]+);\s+blah=foo/ )[0] } @data) {
    say $r
}
```

Prints `abc12345`, clarified in a comment to be the sought result.

---

Module versions prior to `0.406` (of 2015-03-03) didn't have `firstres` (alias `first_result`)

Comment: Thanks! `first_result` sounds like what I was thinking of, although I think `map` is probably the more elegant solution here (can't believe I didn't think of that earlier...) `first_result` will definitely be something I'll use in future scripts though. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @flashbang Yeah, that's what your question asks for really -- stop at first match but extract a pattern from that element.  Processing input is natural with `map`, unlike what `grep` and `first` do, and that was the first thing that came to mind.  But I left it out altogther because you specifically wanted to avoid "extras" -- code, processing steps, etc. And `map` must, always, pass over the whole list. Efficiency wise that makes practically no difference with lists of a few items but `firstres` just fills the bill more fully. Also, it isn't mentioned often while it can be _very_ useful.

Comment: (Also, efficiency wise, `firstres` must do extra bookkeeping/testing to be able to bail out at first match, so for very short lists it may not be faster at all.)

Comment: Appearance wise, the code for `firstres` and `map` looks _exactly_ the same -- you must explicitly return from the block what you what the operation to return. The only difference is that `firstres` bails out on first match, so there's nothing to do after the fact so it is in fact cleaner looking. I'd guess that  `map` seems more elegant due to habit and common use -- it is a well known and loved builtin meant precisely for processing elements of a list.

Answer (score 2):

`first { ... } @values` returns one the values (or `undef`).

You could use either of these:

```perl
my ($value) = map { /...(...).../ } @values;

my $value = ( map { /...(...).../ } @values ) ? $1 : undef;

my $value = ( map { /...(...).../ } @values )[0];
```

Using `first`, it would look like the following, which is rather silly:

```perl
my $value = first { 1 } map { /...(...).../ } @values;
```

However, assuming the capture can't be an empty string or the string `0`, List::MoreUtils's `first_result` could be used to avoid the unnecessary matches:

```perl
my $value = first_result { /...(...).../ ? $1 : undef } @values;

my $value = first_result { ( /...(...).../ )[0] } @values;
```

If the returned value can be false (e.g. an empty string or a `0`) you can use something like

```perl
my $value = first_result { /...(...).../ ? \$1 : undef } @values;
$value = $$value if $value;
```

The `first_result` approach isn't necessarily faster in practice.

Comment: Thanks! The `map` solution seems like the most elegant one in this scenario in terms of readability - since the list will never be more than a few elements I'm not worried about looping unnecessarily. `first_result` sounds like what I was asking for, even if it's not what I ended up going with here :)

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet is looking for `foo` stored in a variable `$find`, the found values is stored in variable `$found`.

```
my $find = 'foo';
my $found;

while( $response->header( 'X-Header' ) ) {
    if( /X-Header: .*?blah=($find)/ ) {
        $found = $1;
        last;
    }
}

say $found if $found;
```

Sample demo code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $find = 'foo';
my $found;
my @header = <DATA>;

chomp(@header);

for ( @header ) {
    $found = $1 if /X-Header: .*?blah=($find)/;
    last if $found;
}

say Dumper(\@header);
say "Found: $found" if $found;

__DATA__
X-Header: test-abc12345; blah=foo
X-Header: test-fgasjhgakg; blah=bar
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'X-Header: test-abc12345; blah=foo',
          'X-Header: test-fgasjhgakg; blah=bar'
        ];

Found: foo
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `X-Header` is returned for all responses - I need to check if a foo value was provided to know whether to continue or not.

Comment: Do you use [HTTP::Respose](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response)? Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide.

Comment: Yes, I'm using LWP - sorry, should have included that I suppose. I didn't think getting into the specifics would be very helpful since this API is not public, but the `header` method of an HTTP::Response object should work the same anywhere.

Comment: Please see sample demo code and it's output. I utilized `__DATA__` block to simulate `X-Header`.